# How to call a function with arguments from a String?

Tags: java

If I have a `String` that contains a command and I want the program to read it and  preform what it says.

**example:**

If I have a function:

```
private void move(float position, float speed){
.....
}
```

and a `String`

```
String command = "MOVE 305 5"
```

where the "MOVE"  calls the  `move()`  function and  “305“  is the position and the  “5“  is the speed.

So,  it should be like this:

```
move(305, 5);
```

How can I call the function using this String?

Comment: If all of your strings will be following the format of `COMMAND arg1 arg2 argN` then why not use [`String#Split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

Comment: You should learn about "reflection" in Java. With reflection you can use a string as input to invoke an existing method.

Comment: @IQV No reflection needed here. From experience, it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @IQV true, but for something like this it's not a very optimal solution. This just requires some simple parsing.

Comment: user3879781 provided the move-command as an example. According to his profile he's interested in game-developing. So I think "move" will not be the only command, so it's necessary to use a broad approach.

Comment: @IQV so? Still no need for reflection.

Comment: Nice one. Congrats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all of your commands are in the same format, you should have a switch statement, that will switch between the possible commands you may have. This way, you will call each function when it is needed with the args from the string.

**Example:**

```
String[] parts = command.split(' ');
switch(parts[0])
{
    case "MOVE":
        float position = Float.parseFloat(parts[1])
        float speed = Float.parseFloat(parts[2])
        move(position, speed);
        break;

    case ... :

    ...

    default:
        System.out.println("Unknown command");
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use an Enumeration for the different possible commands, along with a switch-case as already shown in other answers .

The enumeration :

```
 public enum CommandType{

        MOVE, STOP;
 }
```

And a sample usage :

```
String[] splitted = command.split("\\s");

CommandType currentCommand = CommandType.valueOf(splitted[0]);


switch(currentCommand){

    case MOVE : 
        move(Float.parseFloat(splitted[1]),Float.parseFloat(splitted[2]));
        break;
    case STOP : 
        stop();
        break;
    default :
        break;
}
```